# How can I get a list of functions a protocol defines?

Tags: objective-c, reflection

I know there is `protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList` defined in the Objective-C Runtime, but I don't want to have to go so deep, or work with c-arrays. Are there any methods for the `Protocol` object that can do this? Where can I find any documentation for the `Protocol` object? I'm hoping for something like:

`[foo getMethodsThisProtocolDefines]`;

where foo is a `Protocol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [this.](https://github.com/mikeash/MAObjCRuntime) Objective-C wrapper for the Objective-C runtime.

Answer (score 5):

The `Protocol` class has been deprecated since Leopard/ObjC 2.0.* Thus, there are no methods on it, nor any current documentation. The only way to interact with a protocol is via the runtime functions.

The structures contained in the protocol's method list aren't objects, either, so they couldn't go into an `NSArray` without being wrapped anyways.

It's not particularly arduous to deal with the array that's returned from `protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList()`; you just have to remember to `free()` it. If you have a particular selector in mind, you can also check the protocol using `protocol_getMethodDescription()`, which doesn't require any memory management on your part. For example:

```
BOOL method_description_isNULL(struct objc_method_description desc)
{
    return (desc.types == NULL) && (desc.name == NULL);
}

const char * procure_encoding_string_for_selector_from_protocol(SEL sel, Protocol * protocol)
{
    static BOOL isReqVals[4] = {NO, NO, YES, YES};
    static BOOL isInstanceVals[4] = {NO, YES, NO, YES};
    struct objc_method_description desc = {NULL, NULL};
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
        desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(protocol,
                                             sel,
                                             isReqVals[i], 
                                             isInstanceVals[i]);
        if( !method_description_isNULL(desc) ){
            break;
        }
    }

    return desc.types;
}
```

---

*In fact, it seems (based on [a note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BBCEFDIE) in the runtime reference) that the name is now just an alias for `Class`.

Answer (score 1):

Check [protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418822-protocol_copymethoddescriptionli?language=objc#) from Objective-C runtime. This would return back an array of methods on the protocol.